# Proper way of Mongoose testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose

I have a problem with testing Mongoose models in Node.js. Every course and tutorial I've seen require to run instance of MongoDB.I'm aware of mongodb-memory-server package, but it's still running some kind of server. For me necessity of running whole database just for testing is a bit odd. Especially that using working database prevents me from running my tests in parallel since before each test I need to connect to database, remove all existing data from it and disconnect from database after each test. All that cause that around 20 tests I created for one model take around 5 seconds to execute. Am I missing something or it's really a necessity?

Comment: what features of a model would you like to test? If anything you are testing will execute some query you will need a db server also you can mock your models.

Comment: I want to test everything that is defined by my. Validators, static model methods and what is most difficult for me - virtual fields, that are relations to other models. I've recently discovered how to test most of that using mocks, but still some of my tests required connection to real database. What I really wanted to know is whether or not tests that require connection to database (and still test only small part of code, so I can call them unit tests) are good practice.

Comment: the essence of testing code is to verify that your solutions actually solves the right problem. Once you have that covered, every other thing is semantic. You are in the right track I think.